# Ability to zoom in/out and shaking canvas on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, ipad

We have been trying to build a map for a client where users can:

- Use a joystick to navigate left and right
- Zoom in/out on the canvas
- Select a specific building and have that center align for them

Everything works great on a PC but when we try to use an iPad 2 problems happen:

- The screen becomes quite shaky
- When you zoom in on the screen the quality of the map drops, even though the map is over 10mb and the quality is good for some reason it becomes pixelated.

URL: http://bit.ly/1MDcVhV

Does anyone have experience with such problems.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post zoom code for touch devices

Comment: @PauliusS. Actually his problem is how to display this image http://goo.gl/VnhM8c on iPad with Good Quanlity like on Desktop Browsers.

Comment: 2) About image quality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542045/mobile-safari-downsamples-large-images-how-to-retain

Comment: When you zooming with touch devices screen becomes quite shaky with iPad only or other touch devices like a android smartphones,tablets ?

Comment: @PauliusS. with android we dont face the shake problem, zooming has issues and the quality becomes pixelated again.