# Mobile Safari Mega Pixel limit?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I recently had issues with images larger then 2MP on Mobile Safari.  I have found a some [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542045/mobile-safari-downsamples-large-images-how-to-retain) talking about it but all of them appear to be pointing to a section of documentation that no longer exist.  The closest I found was this old [thread post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4975106?tstart=0).

My question is, does anyone know where the official documentation is for this and what is the Apple recommend way for solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking with developers at WWDC 2016, the documentation about 2MP on Mobile Safari was removed because it is no longer an issue.  If you do encounter a bug that looks similar to the old post, it is most likely a CSS issue.  It was for me.