# draggable background image not displaying on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, draggable

I'm desperate. I've tried a million things to make this image work on desktop and now that it is, I noticed it is not displaying on ipad. It does on my phone (galaxy s3) but it is not draggable!! :(

It is a world map and want it to start on Europe but be able to drag it so you can see the entire picture.

You'll probably be sick when you look at this code... sorry!!!

HTML

```
</div>
    <div id="screen"><h6>CTS WORLDWIDE INSTALLATIONS</h6>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#screen {
display:block;
float:left;
margin:25px 0 0 0;
width:699px; 
height:358px; 
background-image: url(http://ctsmedia.co.uk/_images/desktop/EMEA_map.png);
background-position: 50% 35%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $bg = $('#screen'),
    elbounds = {
        w: parseInt($bg.width()),
        h: parseInt($bg.height())
    },
    bounds = {w: 3609 - elbounds.w, h: 1858 - elbounds.h},
    origin = {x: -1361, y: -315},
    start = {x: -1361, y: -315},
    movecontinue = false;

function move (e){
    var inbounds = {x: false, y: false},
        offset = {
            x: start.x - (origin.x - e.clientX),
            y: start.y - (origin.y - e.clientY)
        };

    inbounds.x = offset.x < 0 && (offset.x * -1) < bounds.w;
    inbounds.y = offset.y < 0 && (offset.y * -1) < bounds.h;

    if (movecontinue && inbounds.x && inbounds.y) {
        start.x = offset.x;
        start.y = offset.y;

        $(this).css('background-position', start.x + 'px ' + start.y + 'px');
    }

    origin.x = e.clientX;
    origin.y = e.clientY;

    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}

function handle (e){
    movecontinue = false;
    $bg.unbind('mousemove', move);

    if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
        origin.x = e.clientX;
        origin.y = e.clientY;
        movecontinue = true;
        $bg.bind('mousemove', move);
    } else {
        $(document.body).focus();
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}

function reset (){
    start = {x: 0, y: 0};
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
}

$bg.bind('mousedown mouseup mouseleave', handle);
$bg.bind('dblclick', reset);
});
</script>
```

Any ideas for this hopeless designer would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Ps.: Oh, and I don't know anything about scripting. Not even the difference between jquery and javascript... I'm a self learner

Comment: try using `$bg.bind('mousedown mouseup mouseleave touch touchstart touchend', handle);` in your 4th line from last in your code ! there are no events supporting touch devices in your code. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll give it a try, however I think it could be a size issue and dKen pointed below. I will add that line though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big is your image? Mobile Safari has a suggested limit of 1024x1024 for images for memory considerations, and I've had it act unpredictably when going over that size. I suggest trying a smaller image for mobile/tablets. See:

[Image size limitations in mobile safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725851/image-size-limitations-in-mobile-safari)

**Edit:** I just saw it is 3609x2105 pixels. Try a smaller version

Comment: I'm going to try this. The image is huge and that could be the reason. Thanks!

Comment: It was that man. Thanks very much. I need to find a solution now for the issue of not being able to see the icons properly...